# Can You Transmit with Airband Transceiver

Tags: usa, radio-communications

I am considering the purchase of two Dittel FSG-5 Airband (118-137 Mhz) transceivers. If I transmit from one radio to the other, and vice versa, am I breaking any rules or potentially causing an issue with pilot/ground crew transmissions?

Comment: One note: with radio, you never transmit from one device **to** another device. Your transmissions are sent into the void for anyone else to listen in on. (You may be able to encrypt your transmission but it will still be broadcast into the void.)

Comment: In which country would you use the equipment?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using them for aviation purposes or for an emergency, yes, you would be breaking the law, and yes, there is a significant possibility of interfering with aviation-related communications. This will apply in virtually any country.

If you do use them for aviation, and you are a pilot using a radio in an aircraft, then that should be legal. At least in the US, I do not believe any license is required other than your pilot certificate. In other aviation-related contexts, you may be able to obtain a license; I am not familiar with this process, but expect your use of the radios to be strictly regulated, if your license is granted at all.

If you just want personal communications, for non-aviation purposes, a service such as [Family Radio Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Radio_Service) (in the US) or [PMR446](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMR446) (in Europe and the UK) may be more suitable. Transceivers for these bands should be readily available from sites like Amazon, and possibly from some brick-and-mortar retailers.

Depending on laws in your jurisdiction, and the willingness of you and the other people to whom you want to talk to pay license fees, do some paperwork (or online forms), and possibly take some tests on radio theory and regulations, a licensed service such as [General Mobile Radio Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Mobile_Radio_Service) (US-only) or [amateur (ham) radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) (available in almost all countries, but licensing procedures vary widely) may be an option.

One word of caution regarding amateur radio: many amateur transceivers are available on Amazon without being clearly marked as amateur radios. These include, but are not limited to, "Baofeng," "TYT," and "Radioddity" brand radios. Before purchasing a radio, check the laws in your country and make sure the radio is designed for use within a service that is available in your country, and that you have a license if one is required. Of course, if you have an amateur radio license, it is OK to use amateur transceivers as long as you follow the regulations.

[Citizens' Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens_band_radio) is available in many countries as well. In the US and many other countries, you do not need a license; in some others, a license is required.

Comment: Good Lord! It is what I feared, especially when you add in randomhead's kind comment, that the transmission from the TX device goes "into the void" as a public broadcast, much akin to CB transmissions. So, bottom line, having a pair of the devices is about as useful as a bathtub without a drain connected to it. Did I miss anything? Thanks for everyone's help, I'll stick with my Autophon and Stornophone UHF radios.

Comment: @GaryBrant FYI, that's true of any radio. Every bit of spectrum is allocated to specific uses. You need to make sure your transmissions are in a band that you are legally permitted to use.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. But one has to ask - where are the warnings about this subject from retailers like Amazon, that extoll ICOM and other makers aviation radios. I mean, if you're going to listen to chatter, innocent enough, why not just use a scanner?

Comment: @GaryBrant I don't know why warnings aren't posted, but it is a general thing that operating most radios requires a license. This applies to aviation radios as well as HF/VHF/UHF radios except in a few specific bands.

Comment: @GaryBrant what country are you in? I could add more details that will be relevant to your situation if I know what country you're in.

Comment: I'm a New Yorker, thank you for your help. Gary

Comment: Another quick question, I must assume the operator's location eg. how far you are from an airport is immaterial. In other words, a transmit might interfere with a plane flying overhead, within range of your radio. Is that about right? Thanks again, Gary Brant

Comment: @GaryBrant thank you! Since you're in the US, FRS sounds like the best option for you, or maybe GMRS or CB if you need more range. Being far from an airport makes interference less likely, but certainly does not eliminate the risk, and distance to an airport has no effect on legality.

Comment: "*At least in the US, I do not believe any license is required*", no licence for the US, but an  [operator certificate](https://www.aopa.org/travel/international-travel/aircraft-radio-station-licenses-and-pilot-radio-operator-certificates).

Comment: @mins yes, it's required for international flights.

Comment: @GaryBrant no clue why anyone would use a transceiver rather than a pure receiver if they don't have any business transmitting. Of course if you have a transceiver anyway and are wanting to use it for reception only on occasion, why buy a receiver for those days only? Of course there might be laws prohibiting use outside of strictly defined parameters (like we have here, can't use a transceiver at all outside a licensed vehicle or location, and need a special license and permit for each one).